# @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI - can't toggle bool

Tags: swift, environment-variables, global-variables, swiftui

I have the class below to keep the state of the hamburger menu if it is or not displayed

```
class Menu: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive: Bool = false
}
```

I instantiate it in Scene Delegate as such

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(Menu())
```

Then in a simple view i am trying to toggle the isActive bool, however i get the error below

```
struct Button: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var menuState: Menu

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Button(action: {
                self.menuState.isActive.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("A")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error i get: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Button' with an argument list of type '(action: @escaping () -> (), @escaping () -> Text)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you named your custom `View` as `Button`, which is also the name of the existing `SwiftUI` button.

Simply rename your `struct` to something else and your code will compile just fine.

Unrelated to your question, but there's no point in wrapping a single `View` in a `VStack`, your `body` can simply contain the `Button`.

```
struct MyButton: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var menuState: Menu

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.menuState.isActive.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("A")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a custom view named `Button` which is in conflict with the native SwiftUI `Button` (because they have the same name).

Rename your `Button` view and it will be okey I think.

Comment: thanks! Indeed it worked! Initially i wrapped the button in a VStack since i wasn;t sure where the error was coming from and thought it is due to the Button not wrapped in a  Vstack.